# Closing Excel application that was created in a different function

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have two functions in one .vbs file:

```
Function OpenTarget(ByVal reviewPeriod)
    ' check if file exists
    Dim FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FileExists("FILE_" & reviewPeriod) Then
        ' the target file is created for the first time for the given reviewPeriod, hence open the template
        Set objExcel_target                       = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel_target.Application.Visible       = True
        objExcel_target.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set OpenTarget                            = objExcel_target.Workbooks.Open("FILE_" & reviewPeriod)
    Else
        ' the target file is created for the first time for the given reviewPeriod, hence open the template
        Set objExcel_target                       = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel_target.Application.Visible       = True
        objExcel_target.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set OpenTarget                            = objExcel_target.Workbooks.Open("FILE_TEMPLATE")
    End If
End Function

Function CloseTarget(target, reviewPeriod)
    ' Save and close workbook
    target.SaveAs "Path_To_Another_File"
    target.Close (False)

    objExcel_target.Application.Quit
End Function
```

Now I would like to use these two functions in a third function, which is located in a second .vbs file. The script fails at this point:

```
objExcel_target.Application.Quit
```

I understand that `CloseTarget()` does not know about the `objExcel_target` but how can I eventually also close the application using the CloseTarget function?

Comment: I guess it's not just a case of changing `objExcel_target.Application.Quit` to `target.Application.Quit`?

Comment: No - unfortunately not. target is a workbook, which i can Close(). objExcel_target is an application, which i simply want to Quit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you close a workbook you don't have access to its properties anymore. Get the application from the workbook before closing it:

```
Function CloseTarget(target, reviewPeriod)
    Set xl = target.Application

    ' Save and close workbook
    target.SaveAs "Path_To_Another_File"
    target.Close (False)

    xl.Quit
End Function
```

You can't use `objExcel_target` because that appears to be a local variable in the function `OpenTarget()`.

Comment: Cool! This does the job. Thanks!!